# rails 6, minitest and devise valid record yet create count incorrect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, minitest

The following test:

```
  test "create with mobile" do
    assert @user_mobile.valid?, @user_mobile.errors.full_messages.inspect
puts assert @user_mobile.valid?
    assert_difference('User.count') do
      post users_url, params: { user: { mobile: @user_mobile.mobile, name_first: @user_mobile.name_first, name_last: @user_mobile.name_last, nation_id: @user_mobile.nation_id, mobile_nation_id: @user_mobile.mobile_nation_id, password: '11111111', password_confirmation: '11111111', idiom_id: @user_mobile.idiom_id } }
    end
  end
```

passes the first assertion and is returning to the console

```
true
F

Failure:
UsersControllerTest#test_create_with_mobile [/Volumes/SanJuanT/r/market/test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:29]:
"User.count" didn't change by 1.
```

Thus, the non creation of the record is not due to a validation error.

How can one trace the point in the process where devise fails to create the record?

**Update**
Logs indicate a series of unpermitted parameters (all of the above, save password related ones).

```
Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"user"=>{"mobile"=>"3331112200", "name_first"=>"MyString", "name_last"=>"MyString", "nation_id"=>"1", "mobile_nation_id"=>"1",
```

yet the `registrations_controller`, has a protected block for sign_up (and update) strong parameters:

```
def configure_sign_up_params
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit({ roleshopusers: [:role_id, :shop_id, :user_id] }, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :mobile, :mobile_nation_id, [...])
```

adding those parameters to the alternate lazy way, also suggested in devise ReadMe

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :mobile [...]
```

initiates a process, but rolls back

```
User Exists? [...]
ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT active_record_1
```

as this is a test, I do not imaging that the test would consider a fixture as already existing.

**  Solution (possible) **

Changing the reference to a string that was *not* referenced in the fixtures.

```
post users_url, params: { user: { mobile: ' 3331 91 220 0 ',
```

log

```
User Create (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[32mINSERT INTO "users" ("encrypted_password", "mobile", "mobile_nation_id", "login_name", "nation_id"[...]
[1m[36mTRANSACTION (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mRELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
```

As the model had

```
validates :mobile, uniqueness: { scope: :nation_id, message: (I18n.t('user.define_one_mobile_per_nation')) }, if: -> { mobile.present? }
```

Given devise has `authentication_keys` that must be unique, recalling one of the fixtures is forcing the rollback.

Comment: I suggest to look at the test logs . Are you positive a user was being created?

Comment: Correct; blinded myself. still odd because it is liting unpermitted parameters when they are in the protected registrations_controller block `  def configure_sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit({ roleshopusers: [:role_id, :shop_id, :user_id] }, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :mobile, :mobile_nation_id,`

Comment: if you're still having trouble edit your question and provide more info, happy to help further

Comment: question updated.

Comment: The rollback usually indicates a validation is failing. the way to troubleshoot it could be by putting a breakpoint in your controller after the call to save or create and checking for errors, e.g @user.errors

Comment: I believe I found it (q updated), but it is rather counter-intuitive to the way tests are by design.  Either that or I am missing something big.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure I understand. Rails loads all your fixtures before your tests run, that is what they're supposed to do.

Comment: Correct; I was confusing the regular unique `id` keys with the devise  `authentication_keys`.